# Android applications stack like view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

Hello everyone,
              I am looking to build an application stack like view. If you press square button on phone ( Oppo, Samsung and pixel ) you see a view like images below. I m trying to do the same thing. Can anyone tell me a bit what this view is? Is this is sdk or I have to create a custom view like this one? Please see the images. Is this a view_pager? **I m talking about the central part which swipes right and left.**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: User view pager to move left and right. Your activity must use dialog theme which is transparent so you will get the exactly same out put like this.

Comment: view pager holds the whole screen with one item. This is one is not holding it like that.

Comment: Your main activity contains background. Your fragment layout set with margin for e.g. Margin = 50. and your fragment top layout should be transparent By this way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries which make it easier to make all kinds of different looks for recyclerviews. I suggest you search for circular recyclerview in google.
Here is my first search which looks suitable to your needs:
https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

Comment: Thank you for pointing me In the right direction. I was fooling around. :D

Comment: No problem. Good luck!